# magento 2 EE should not save search terms with zero search results

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.8, search-terms

I am using magento 2.1.8 Enterprise edition. I do not want to save search terms which have zero search results. Is there any solution ?

There is no option in configuration to stop saving the search terms with 0 search results.
Please help.

Comment: Anyone else have solution for this?  I used the below module , it is not saving search terms with 0 search results but it increments the uses in admin by 2 . 
we are also using mirasvit catalog search extension.
After disabling the module, the default functionality increments the uses by 1 only.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Create a custom module and create following files.

File: etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Search\Model\Query">
        <plugin name="save_greater_then_zero_search_results" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Query" />
    </type>
</config>
```

File: Plugin/Query.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class Query
{
    public function aroundSaveIncrementalPopularity($subject, $callable)
    {
        return $subject;
    }

    public function aroundSaveNumResults($subject, $callable, $numResults)
    {
        if($numResults > 0)
        {
            $subject->getResource()->saveIncrementalPopularity($subject);
            $subject->setNumResults($numResults);
            $subject->getResource()->saveNumResults($subject);
        }

        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Replace [Vendor] and [Module] with your actual vendor and module name.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou. It works.

Comment: there is a issue, after using this code the number of uses in search terms under marketing is increasing by 2.  Please help.

Comment: The line  $subject->getResource()->saveIncrementalPopularity($subject);  is saving the uses with an increment of 2. whereas It should save with One incremented value.

Comment: checking for it. Will get back to you in sometime.

Comment: Not sure, why this is happening this way, i checked with commenting my code and it still auto increament by 2 ...

Comment: Nope after disabling this module it is incrementing by 1, Please check there is some issue.

Comment: I am looking for the solution , please try to help. why it is incrementing by 2 . 
And after disabling this module it is working fine, and is incrementing by 1 only.

Comment: Alright will check thoroughly.. Will update you

Comment: hello, sorry having no solution as of now from my end.

Comment: the issue is with above module right ?

Comment: for me, i have checked with default magento installation and it also increments by 2. When you search for the same keyword 4-5 times, db adds +1 to popularity and update row and then again search with the new keyword, it adds new row with +5 auto increment.